# How Does The Graphics Object Effect MeasureString

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

When using the MeasureString method, the method has to be called from a graphics object.

I am currently using me.CreateGraphics() from a form object to create the graphics object, but I would like to use this method in a class where passing the form object is not necessary.

---

My question in context is,

Can I declare a dummy graphics object to use MeasureString accurately or are there certain settings within the graphics object that can potentially effect the accuracy of MeasureString?

Or more generally, what effects does the Graphics object have on the MeasureString method.

The code I have so far works. I just want to make sure there isn't a caveat to doing this. Like some edge case of some sort.

```
Public Shared Function GetTextLength(text As String, height As Single) As Single

    height *= 72
    Dim f As New Form()
    Dim boxGraphics As Graphics = f.CreateGraphics()
    Dim sSize As SizeF = boxGraphics.MeasureString(text, New Font("Monotxt", height))
    Dim iInches As Single = sSize.Width / boxGraphics.DpiX

    Return iInches

End Function
```

Comment: See the [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext) method. It has an overload that accepts a Graphics object, but it's used as a *hint*. You can use the internal graphics' cache, passing just the Font and the Text to measure. Much depends on what you're measuring and for what reason (the context always matters, in a way or another).

Comment: I suggest to always use the overload that allows to specify formatting flags: [TextFormatFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags).

Comment: Looks ok. The influence is the use of dpi setting, which will be screen resolution if you create it from any control or form. Not sure which complications could arise in a multiscreen setup, though.